# select a chunk with maximum score in a string python

Tags: python, algorithm

This is more like an algorithm question but I have a feeling that python has a neat way to do this.

Lets say I have a string:

```
      string = " this is how i do is it..is this is how we do it.. this is how everyone do it is"
```

Now I basically want to extract the most important chunk from the string.
How I am deciding the "most important" is basically just by looking into term frequency.
so lets say if i want a chunk which is 10 chars/words (basically a fixed window) long, then basically i am trying to find the chunk whose terms have maximum term frequency score.

So in the example above, probably "is" the most repeated term.
so maybe the best chunk is

```
                   "is this is"
```

or someting like that.??
How do i do this in python efficiently (This is for the python community)

Is there a better way to approach this (This is for the algorithm community)

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify your requirements a bit better. For example, specifying chunks as characters, but 'repeated terms' as sequences of words, already makes what you asking very difficult, if not impossible. Are you sure you can't just say 'I want to know the most frequently occurring 3 or 4 or 5 word phrases', and forget about character chunks? For example, it looks like 'this is how' is the most frequently occurring 3-word phrase in your example. But you really want 10 characters?

Comment: @alan: so its more like having a moving window on your words. This window is of fixed size and then selecting the window which has the maximum score.. In general, it is like moving one word at a time.. retreiving all the words in that window.. calculating the score and the iterating it.. this doesnt look that difficult if i implement in naive way?? something like for i,word in enumerate(words): last_index = i + window 
if last_index > len(words):
  break
else get all the words in the window and calculate their score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try:

I am given each letter (space including) a score. The score is equal to the number of times the element shows up in a string. The find a 10 element window who sum of element score is maximized.

```
string = " this is how i do is it..is this is how we do it.. this is how everyone do it is"

from collections import Counter 

s_count = Counter(string)

def score_count(x):
    return sum(s_count[ele] for ele in x)

most_imp = None
high_val = 0
n = 10   

for i in xrange(0, len(string) - n):

    temp_value = score_count(string[i: i + n])

    if temp_value > high_val:
        high_val = temp_value
        most_imp = string[i : i + n]
```

Result:

```
>>> most_imp
' i do is i'
```

Comment: hi.. what is "string"? is that the original text?

Comment: I could be wrong but the fist line after the if should be a call to the score_count function like the call made for the comparation. I mean: high_val = score_count(string[i : i + n]), don't you think?

Comment: @GustavoVargas, you are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you build counts dictionary for each word. It should be straightforward to get the substring that has maximum sum of counts from here.

```
import re
tokens = re.findall(r'\w+', string)
counts = {}
for i in tokens:
    counts[i]=counts.get(i,0)+1
```

Comment: Right. This is what I was getting ready to post, but it doesn't answer his question. He only wants 10-character 'windows', including spaces. So word counts don't really help. (Unless I'm misreading his requirements, which is possible.)

Comment: @alan: oh let me edit that. i can have fixed chars or words.. basically a fixed window in the text string

Comment: I think word counts matter because he says 'find the chunk whose terms have maximum term frequency score'. But it is not obvious what he is going to do if 10 letter window truncates some words into other valid words (eg. "IS THIS ISis").

Comment: @Fraz So a 3 (or 4?) word window is what you want?